# having two tables display at once javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I found a script to change the color of every seccond row to make it look nice, but when i add another table on the same page it colours the first table but the seccond table gets no colour why is this??

code of table.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //for tables style
    function altRows(id){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName){  

        var table = document.getElementById(id);  
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

        for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){          
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                rows[i].className = "evenrowcolor";
            }else{
                rows[i].className = "oddrowcolor";
            }      
        }
    }
}
window.onload=function(){
    altRows('alternatecolor');
}



});
```

php webpage code:

```
  <?php 
//first table
       echo'
           <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
      <tr>
      <th>Seller</th>
      <th>price(per 1k doge)</th>
      <th>payment allowed</th>
      <th>View Trade</th>
      </tr>

      <td>Example</td>
        <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
        </tr>';



     echo'</table> <br />';  


//seccond table
 echo  '<h3>trades on going </h3>';

    echo ' <table class="gridtable">
     <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
        <tr>
        <th>Trade User</th>
        <th>Cost($)</th>
        </tr>

     <td>Example</td>
        <td>Example</td>
          <td>Example</td>
        </tr>';

     echo'</table> ';  

?>
```

Comment: dont do it by id. do it by class

Answer (score 3):

A better way to do this is via CSS.

```
tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: black, color: white }
tr:nth-child(even) { background color: white, color: black }
```

This will apply to all tables on your page, without having to mess about with the HTML as output by your PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the first table by its id `alternatecolor` when you call `document.getElementById(id)`. Perhaps add an id to your second table, then call `altRows` again for it?

Editing the second table in the PHP File:

`echo ' <table class="gridtable" id="secondTable">`

Editing the JavaScript:

```
window.onload=function(){
    altRows('alternatecolor');
    altRows('secondTable');
}
```

Comment: coudent figuar out how to do it and your way just fixed it for me thanks :)